# SQL Server query listing duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL query that pulls a list of contacts from a small database; it pulls the data just fine. However the problem with the SQL is the fact that it will list the same contact multiple times depending on the number of emails and address associated with the contact.

It's only supposed to list it once. Here's the SQL I've written:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                Contact_Main.contactid, first_name, last_name, p_title,
                prefix, suffix, email, address1, address2, 
                city, state, zip, Contact_Address_Type.addresstype, 
                Contact_Email_Types.emailtype, 
                addressid, emailid, Contact_Address_Type.addresstypeid, 
                Contact_Email_Types.emailtypeid,
                (SELECT COUNT(addressid) 
                       FROM Contact_Address 
                       WHERE contactid = Contact_Main.contactid) as num_addresses,
                (SELECT COUNT(emailid) 
                        FROM Contact_Email 
                        WHERE contactid = Contact_Main.contactid) as num_emails
        FROM Contact_Main
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Email ON Contact_Main.contactid = 
                                                    Contact_Email.contactid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Email_Types ON Contact_Email_Types.emailtypeid =
                                                    Contact_Email.emailtypeid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Address ON Contact_Address.contactid = 
                                                    Contact_Main.contactid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Address_Type ON Contact_Address_Type.addresstypeid  = 
                                                    Contact_Address.addresstypeid 
        ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix and that I need to make some part of this a sub query but for some reason I can't figure it out.

Comment: can you show us the output you get ? and your desired output?

Comment: What is the query supposed to do when a contact has multiple email addresses or addresses?  The repeated rows appear to be by design.

Comment: It sounds like you don't care about the emails/addresses if you only need a single listing.  In that case, just `GROUP BY Contact_Main.contactid`

Comment: @ElVieejo: I'll have to do that when I go to work tommorrow.

Comment: @Gorden Linoff: It's only supposed to list one, yet like you said it lists more than one by the way it's structed. Which isn't what I want.

Comment: @Madbreaks: I'll try that when I go to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

so this works fine ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                cm.contactid
                , first_name
                , last_name
                , p_title
                , prefix
                , suffix
                , email
                , address1
                , address2
                , city
                , state
                , zip
                , cat.addresstype
                , cet.emailtype
                , addressid
                , emailid
                , cat.addresstypeid
                , cet.emailtypeid
                --, (SELECT COUNT(addressid) 
                --     FROM Contact_Address 
                --     WHERE contactid = cm.contactid) as num_addresses
                --, (SELECT COUNT(emailid) 
                --      FROM Contact_Email 
                --      WHERE contactid = cm.contactid) as num_emails
        FROM Contact_Main cm
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Email ce ON cm.contactid = 
                                                    ce.contactid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Email_Types cet ON cet.emailtypeid =
                                                    ce.emailtypeid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Address ON ca.contactid = 
                                                    cm.contactid
        LEFT JOIN Contact_Address_Type ON cat.addresstypeid  = 
                                                    ca.addresstypeid 
        ORDER BY cm.last_name, cm.first_name;
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. That's pretty much the same thing as what I have only the you gave aliases to the tables without declaring them with AS keyword and commenting out the sub-query each gives count to the email and addresses associated with the contacts. I copy and pasted it in and it threw an error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so when I was at work I asked my boss what was the deal with SQL code. We both took a look at it and he determined that it was returning every possible outcome. After messing around with a simulation in SQL Access it turns out we had to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of just a LEFT JOIN.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Contact_Main.contactid, first_name, last_name, p_title,
                    prefix, suffix, email, address1, address2, 
                    city, state, zip, Contact_Address_Type.addresstype, 
                    Contact_Email_Types.emailtype, 
                    addressid, emailid, Contact_Address_Type.addresstypeid, 
                    Contact_Email_Types.emailtypeid,
  (SELECT COUNT(addressid) FROM Contact_Address 
   WHERE contactid = Contact_Main.contactid) as num_addresses,
  (SELECT COUNT(emailid) FROM Contact_Email 
  WHERE contactid = Contact_Main.contactid) as num_emails
  FROM Contact_Main
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact_Email 
  ON Contact_Main.contactid = Contact_Email.contactid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact_Email_Types
  ON Contact_Email_Types.emailtypeid = Contact_Email.emailtypeid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact_Address 
  ON Contact_Address.contactid = Contact_Main.contactid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact_Address_Type 
  ON Contact_Address_Type.addresstypeid  = Contact_Address.addresstypeid 
  ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

And that did the trick. Thanks for all the suggestions!